# How to put an asterisk when typing the password in the linux terminal for all users?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, password

I know how to add asterisks when sudo users type their password (https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/make-sudo-password-visible-terminal)

But when a user without sudo permission needs or wants to change their password, I don't know how to do the same. How do I make all ubuntu users typing their passwords see asterisks?

cheers

Comment: If this feature existed anywhere, it would be in part of the PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module) system. According to [Show Asterisks when changing Password](https://www.unix.com/303002797-post2.html), it used to exist, but doesn't anymore - however I cannot find any corroboration of this in the PAM changelog

Comment: You haven't given your release (thus what desktop you're using), nor what tool you are using to change passwords. If I change passwords using the *User and Group Settings* **dots** appear as I type each character without any change; why does it need to be asterisks??  https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.15/users_and_groups.html

Comment: We use ubuntu 18.04 for multiusers and users without sudo permission when they need to change their own password have difficulty because nothing appears in the terminal when typing (especially older users or those with little familiarity with linux)

Comment: You tagged Lubuntu, are you using the GUI tools? or CLI? ie. what tool are you asking about?  (*you do mention terminal, but GUI tools can be initiated from terminal so that is rather unspecific*)

Comment: I just booted a Lubuntu 18.04 LTS system, and `users-admin` uses dots too as old & new password is entered. It can be run without `sudo` access (*unless you're trying to change the passwords of other users than yourself of course*)

Comment: I put lubuntu, because we use ubuntu 18.04 with lxde interface. Access is remote via chrome remote desktop, x2go or ssh. Actually changing the password via the GUI would be an alternative, but my question is more focused on whether through the terminal (command line) it is possible for the user to change the password with asteristics appearing when the user types in the "passwd".

Comment: The `passwd` command doesn't show any characters by design (it's more secure as if dots/asterisks are shown, someone else who can view the screen can see how many characters were typed giving more information).  If you want a terminal command to do it, just create a script that gathers the change (showing asterisks or anything you like) & then shells out to existing tools to actually perform the change silently.

Comment: I know this is an older question. But I found this answer that helped me solve the problem: https://www.maketecheasier.com/show-password-asterisks-in-terminal/

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).